# jQuery selector: Not this div and not that div

Tags: jquery, css, click

I am trying to create a jQuery click function that will close a div when you click on anything besides that div. My problem is that there is a search field and another button inside that div that need to stay open if you click on them.

My current function is:

```
$("*:not(#header)").click(function() {
    $('#header').slideUp({
        duration: 550, 
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    });
});
```

I want to also say "and is not '#categoryMore' and is not '#headerSearch'" but the syntax I've been using have not been working.

```
$("*:not(#header, #categoryMore, #headerSearch)")
```

and

```
$("*:not(#header), *:not(#categoryMore), *:not(#headerSearch)")
```

Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I believe `patrick dw` is on the right track here, but the html markup would be nice to see to get specific on the answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have elements that are within the header that you do not want to hide when the header is hidden. Is that the case?

Comment: j-man86 - Well, whatever you end up doing, you do *not* want to add a handler to nearly *every* element on the page by doing `$("*:not(#header)")`. It is terribly inefficient, and really shouldn't be used. Maybe that's the trouble you had with my solution. You need to get rid of that selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here's an example you can test. http://jsfiddle.net/yvFcz/

I used `slideToggle()` for the example so you can more easily test it more than once.

---

Put a handler on the `document` that closes `#header`.

Then place a handler on `#header` that does `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the document when you click inside it.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#header:visible').slideUp({
        duration: 550, 
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    });
});

$('#header').click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation

Note that if any other elements on the page has a click handler that uses `event.stopPropagation()` or `return false;`, the event won't bubble up to the document, and your `#header` won't close.

In that case, you would need to handle it directly in that handler.

Comment: @j-man86 - Here's an example. (The example uses `slideToggle()` instead.) http://jsfiddle.net/yvFcz/ What didn't work? Are you saying that the `#header` didn't slide? Or that clicking inside the `#header` did make it slide?

Comment: sry :)... to specify, clicking inside the #header div still makes it slide.

Comment: @j-man86 - It shouldn't do that. Make sure you added the `event` parameter to the handler function for `#header` as above. Also make sure you *remove* the code that added a click event to *all* the other elements on the page. `$("*:not(#header)")`

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin [`jQuery outside events`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/) you might want to use:

> With jQuery outside events you can
>   bind to an event that will be
>   triggered only when a specific
>   “originating” event occurs outside 
>   the element in question. For example,
>   you can click outside, double-click
>   outside, mouse-over outside, focus
>   outside (and over ten more default
>   “outside” events). Also, if an outside
>   event hasn’t been provided by default,
>   you can easily define your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [jQuery `not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and it might be as simple as this:

```
$(document).not('#header, #categoryMore, #headerSearch').click(function() {
    $('#header').slideToggle({
        duration: 550, 
        easing: 'easeOutExpo'
    });
});
```

This allows you to click anywhere outside of the `#header` and the action will be triggered. You don't have to worry about other `.click()` events and their propagation (at least not to my knowledge)... it will just NOT select `#header, #categoryMore,` and `#headerSearch`.

You can use [jQuery `slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to slide up and down the header and its content whenever you click outside of it. If you only want to hide it, then just use `.slideUp()` as you do now :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hristo - Using `.not()` in that manner won't actually do anything. The `.not()` method is a means of removing elements from a *set* that match the selector given. Since `$(document)` only returns one element (the `document`), and that element will not match the selector given to `.not()`, nothing will be changed.

Comment: @patrick dw... OK I was not aware of that, I'm still pretty new to jQuery. Do you have suggestions on what to replace `$(document)`? We don't have much source code to work with, which is why I went with it in the first place.

Comment: Hristo - Well, if you were to use `.not()` like that, your selector would need to select *all* elements on the page using `$('*')`. Then `.not()` would filter out those few. **But do not do this.** It is terribly inefficient to add a handler to every element. It is better to place a handler only on the `document`, and let the `click` event naturally bubble up to it and fire the handler.

Comment: @patrick dw... Thanks! I hope my solution is not too terrible. I understand now why you chose to answer with the `event.stopPropagation();`. I've used it before, but I just didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Hristo - Your solution above will trigger the `slideToggle()` even if you click the `#header, #categoryMore, #headerSearch` elements. Having the `.not()` there doesn't change the behavior in this case. It's not bad (like adding a handler to every element), but it doesn't quite work the way OP wanted. Thankfully events do bubble up to the `document` element and the bubbling can be disabled where needed through `stopPropagation()`. :o)

Comment: ok COOL! That makes a lot more sense and I see why your solution is better than mine. +1 for taking the time to explain this to me. Thank you!